# PyCharm doesn't allow typing any code problem

Tags: python, pycharm

I have a problem in using PyCharm, that when I make a new project and create a ney python file, I can't write any thing in the python file! the black symbol cant move or earesed and even if I type any thing it does not typed! I don't know where is the problem and can't fond any solution

you can see the problem shown here:

[image: The photo of the problem]

while I can type anything in the Idle that comes when I installed the python, look at the idle:
I am using MAC OSX, PyCharm IDE and Python 3.7.4

I will appreciate your help, thank you very much

Comment: It happens to me sometimes... Try going full screen and back

Comment: how? I have closed the project and re-open it and still it does not solved, also I have let larger the screen to the full screen and still does not solved :(

Answer (score 1):

1. Disable `Tools | Vim Emulator`
2. Remove `ex1.py` from `Preferences | Editor | File Types | Recognized File Types | Text | Registered Patterns`
3. Exclude `venv` by `right-clicking on it in the project tree | Mark Directory as ... | Excluded`